# ActionController::UnknownFormat when creating rss feed in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I'm trying to add a rss feed into my rails 4 app, following this [tuto](http://www.jakobbeyer.de/generate-an-atom-rss-feed-with-ruby-on-rails-for-your-blog), but I'm struggling with a **ActionController::UnknownFormat** that I understand it's happening in my controller.

hacks_controller.rb

```
          def index
            @hacks = Hack.order('id desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 5)
          end

          def feed
            @hacks = Hack.where(:active => true)
            respond_to do |format|
              format.atom { render :template => 'feed.atom.builder', :layout => false }
            end
          end
```

feed.atom.builder

```
        atom_feed {language: 'en-US', url: root_url} do |feed|
          feed.title "My own blog title"
          feed.updated @hacks.maximum(:created_at)

          @hacks.each do |hack|
            feed.entry hack, {published: hack.created_at, updated: hack.updated_at} do |entry|
              entry.title hack.title
              entry.content post.text, type: 'html'
            end
          end
        end
```

I have tried changing

```
 format.atom { render :template => 'feed.atom.builder', :layout => false }
```

to

```
 format.atom { render :layout => false }
```

But still not working.
The trace is

```
            ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:440:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:256:in `respond_to'
               () Users/javier/Desktop/definitive/app/controllers/hacks_controller.rb:14:in `feed'
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
              actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
              activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
```

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In **routes.rb**:

```
get 'feed' => 'hack#feed', format: 'atom'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rss format, so I had to my route

```
defaults => { :format => 'rss' }
```

Try to change format by atom.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add

```
get 'feed' => 'hack#feed', format: 'rss'
```

to the line in routes.rb. `format: 'atom'` didn't work, in spite of its being an atom feed.